# Same command giving different results when run in CLI and when as an argument for os.system()

Tags: python, command-line-interface, os.system

I'm using python to try and scrape twitter data using SNSCRAPE, and for that I need to run the following example command to get the output I want:

```
snscrape --max-results 100 twitter-search '@Tesla @Elonmusk' > scrapedtweets.txt
```

When run on the terminal, it sends the output directly to a text file named 'scrapedtweets'. But when I plug this string into os.system like so:

```
os.system("snscrape --max-results 100 twitter-search '@Tesla @Elonmusk' > scrapedtweets.txt")
```

I get an error code '2', and scrapedtweets.txt remains blank.

I should mention that the command works perfectly in `os.system()` when there are no `@` symbols involved in the command, which leads me to think that it is being parsed funny by the function, but I have no idea what the exact problem is or how to solve it.

Or alternatively is there something wrong with how I am using `os.system()`?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `os.system()` would treat `@` specially.

Comment: I'd try to use one of the functions in `subprocess` and inspect `stderr`

Comment: Anyway, it is a python module so consider using it directly from your Python code and not as a command line tool

Comment: Errno 2 means `No such file or directory`.  You're probably running your Python app in some place where `snscrape` isn't in `$PATH`.  Try running `os.system("env")` and inspect the `PATH=` output shown there.

Comment: Also, what's your OS? Not able to repro on macOS 11.4.

Comment: @Hcaertnit `os.system()` returns the exit status, which is not usually an `errno` code.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking the OP saw code 2 from the output.  Sorry about that!